Next Auth Запрашиваемые доступы отсутствуют у данного приложения (invalid_scope)
Redirect URI(в Яндекс Консоли):
https://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/yandex

signIn:
await signIn("yandex");

provider:
providers: [
    YandexProvder({
        clientId: process.env.YANDEX_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.YANDEX_SECRET
    }),
],

После вызова signIn перебрасывает на страницу с таким изображением:

